# bounded set in $C^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

In Rudin's functional analysis 1.46, he proved  $C^\infty$ is not locally bounded, but in the proof he used a subset $E$ which is bounded. I wonder whether this set is trival.

In general, I wonder if there exists a non-trival bounded subset of a non-locally bounded space.

Here "bounded set $E$" means for each neighborhood $V$ of 0, exists $t$ s.t. $E\subset tV$

Comment: He proves that *every* bounded and closed subset of $C^\infty$ is compact. What do you mean by trivial?

Comment: @Jochen empty set

Comment: @Jochen Is $d(f,0)<1$ a bounded set?

Comment: For example, finite sets and, more generally, compact sets are always bounded. The set $S=\lbrace f: d(f,0)<1\rbrace$ is in general not bounded. If you look at the metric defined by (1) in Rudin's 1.38 you see that (for $c_i \le 1/2$, say) $S$ can be the whole space.

Comment: @Jochen thanks a lot!